# Changing date format in lock screen

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen, time, date, clock

I want to change the date format from what I chose in the Ubuntu installation, and it works by going to Region & Language and selecting the format that I want, but when I log out of the user, the date that is shown in the top of the screen is still the same and hasn't changed.

is there anyway to change the date format for there?

Answer (score 1):

Data and time format are defined as part of the "locale". The system default is configured during installation. You can change the system wide location in the "Language Support" dialog. You can reach the dialog in "Settings", "Region & Language", then hit "Manage Installed Languages", or directly search for "Language Support" in the dash. Hit the "Apply System Wide" button to set the system wide language settings to these of the current account.

[image]

Only a user with administrator rights can do this, obviously.

For more granular control, you need to [directly edit system files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale).